# Fortumo installation: error "Requested service was not found"

Tags: jquery, fortumo

Does anyone have experience with insatlling Fortumo mobile payment?

I have included all of code in my front-end and all I get is lightbox with error message that "Requested service was not found".

Here is my code:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://fortumo.com/javascripts/fortumopay.js" type="text/javascript">  
           </script>
      </head>
<body>
<a id="fmp-button" href="#" rel="b861e82f442de21fcf518527dd2f78d4/74893">
    <img src="http://fortumo.com/images/fmp/fortumopay_96x47.png" width="96" height="47" 
    alt="Mobile Payments by Fortumo" border="0" />
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is documentation for installation:
http://developers.fortumo.com/mobile-payments-for-web-apps/making-a-payment/

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is old - for future reference: the issue here is service type mismatch. The specified service ID is for an API service; the integration code is for cross-platform web payment.